# Ticker gone from Facebook

Tags: facebook

Has anyone yet figured out or found an answer to how to get the ticker back?

<sub>Mine has been gone for weeks and all I do is keep checking forums for a solution.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

From [here's the thing by Ben Patterson](http://heresthethingblog.com/2015/02/03/facebook-tip-hide-ticker/):

> (Update 11/29/2017) Many readers have noted (and as of today, it’s happening to me too) that the ticker has disappeared from their Facebook sidebars, without explanation or any apparent fix. My guess is that Facebook is doing what it always does: fiddling with its features. For now, we’ll just have to wait and see how it all shakes out.